# Reinstall Ubuntu wit UEFI for better performance?

Tags: boot, performance, uefi

I am thinking about reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04 on a freshly formatted disk with BIOS changed to UEFI on my Asus laptop. I hope, it can boost my bootup performance, but am not sure whether it is worth the effort. What do you think?

Comment: Hardware specifications please?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz, 4GiB RAM, ATA Disk 320GB (4 Partitions: NTFS, HFS+, FAT32, EXT4 + SWAP), American Megatrends Inc. BIOS (K54C.207). Enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is the faster boot, and  is that UEFI is better in communication with hardware & firmware. Below are some advantages of using UEFI.

- Ability to boot from large hard drives
- Faster boot-up time
- Support for more than four partitions on a single hard drive
- Better power managment

On a personal note, I haven't really noticed much difference using UEFI with either a SATA II or III hard drives, but a friend has noticed  a difference using an SSD. If you would like to use UEFI go ahead and take a look at [UEFIBooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting)

**Note**: In order to install OS in UEFI mode, you have to have a boot device which contains UEFI bootloader.